# Strange link text in a possible duplicate

Tags: bug, status-completed, exact-duplicates, user-interface

I've just flagged the question [Indefinite integration $\int\frac{(2x^2)}{2xcos(2x)+(x^2-1)(sin(2x))}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3097086/290189) as a possible duplicate of another question posted by the *same* user.  In the link text, a strange sequence of characters appears.  What's the cause of this?  Can this be fixed?

[image]

Comment: Now that the close-as-duplicate vote has been finalized, your auto-generated Comment, which I take it was the "strange link text" you wanted explained, has been auto-removed.  My guess is this happened because the title of the proposed duplicate contains $\LaTeX$ content.  For future reference, the auto-generated Comment that appears with your username can be edited for five minutes, just as with any Comment you manually post.  So you have the chance to improve it  as you see fit at that time.

Comment: Here are more duplicate comments demonstrating the problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097657/convergence-of-infinite-series-complex-numbers#comment6384635_3097657, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3096328/properties-of-this-topology-on-mathbb-n#comment6381961_3096328, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097144/baby-rudin-principles-of-mathematical-analysis-chapter-3-exercise-3#comment6383701_3097144.

Comment: In all cases, the math environments `$ ... $` in the comment are surrounded by the same hex gibberish: `ac98eea9-dfb3-4a03-bf43-d5a071b141c5` preceding it, and `cd44b81e-956e-4b06-9c01-72c8c7d70fef` following it.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks all for your comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry about that... turns out that the markdown parsing process for links in comments is slightly different than the one we run for posts. I have a fix ready for this issue, but I'd like to have it reviewed and do some more testing, so I'm going to hold off until tomorrow morning (NYC time) to deploy it.

In the meantime, editing the affected comments appears to work around the problem. I apologize for the inconvenience.

---

The fix has been deployed and affected comments cleaned up. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Works correctly now, thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Thanks Adam!  I've accepted your answer.  Please keep up your good work!